# Can I replace RAM or processor in new Mac mini?

Tags: upgrade, mac-mini

Is it possible from technical point of view to replace/upgrade on my own RAM or processor in new [Mac mini](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-mac/mac-mini?product=MGEM2LL/A&step=config#) released today (assuming that I'll use compatible replacement)?

Comment: that is way to soon to tell, it was announced 2 hours ago, by my guess, ram is easily accessible, however... thats provided apple hasn't gone to solderd ram the cpu, thats a entirely different task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No RAM or processor replacement in the Mac Mini 2014

An [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac+Mini+Late+2014+Teardown/30410) teardown reveals this. And @Pol posted a link to [macminicolo.net](https://macminicolo.net/blog/files/a-look-at-the-2014-mac-mini) were you can read about the soldered RAM.

The processor and the RAM is soldered onto the motherboard. Even in a clean room, a soldering iron and a steady hand, it would be nearly impossible. You are not allowed to do this on your own, your warranty will expire on this one.

<strike>You can replace your RAM yourself, Apple has even provided a guide on how to do it on similar hardware (2012 model). Here you can find the guide: ["Mac mini: How to remove or install memory"](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4432). No problems with your warranty.</strike>

Comment: I'm not fully convinced on the RAM upgradeability yet - they did say now it's using LPDDR3; isn't that usually the soldered RAM? Also, it sounds like we lost the second SATA port in favor of a PCIe storage port - which is a problem for my own upgrade (since I paid for a 1TB aftermarket SSD and a 2TB data drive...) Guess we'll have to wait for the iFixit teardown! :-)

Comment: Or we need to see the bottom of the device. But 'usually' apple does change the casing with the change of motherboard.

Comment: Dust is not a factor when soldering. Also, iFixit has a terrific teardown of the new mini: https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Mac+Mini+Late+2014+Teardown/30410

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, [we can't](https://macminicolo.net/blog/files/a-look-at-the-2014-mac-mini) replace RAM too. It's soldered.